How to fix the Internal Server Errors and Symfony exceptions on my new Laravel project
When I try to run my laravel project the server starts but on the localhost it gives an internal server error (SQLSTATE[08006] [7] Connection refused Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?) and I've been trying to clear cache, restart postgres, etc... and sometimes when it fixes it gives a Symfony exception Failed to open stream: Permission denied.
I swapped for the Ubuntu LTS 24.04 recently and download docker engine and composer, installed Laravel and created a newly project and as soon as I did the sail up to access it on my web it gave a Symfony exception (Failed to open stream: Permission denied.), Today on my job I Managed to create a laravel project and it all worked out fine so I worked on it, put it on a github repo and cloned it at home, swapped to PostgreSQL (I wanted to use Postgre db because I never used and I was testing it out now) I configured the .env with the right port and address, put the right vendor folder, I made sure I had a database that was working there with the right db name, username and password but it always gave out this Internal Server Error (SQLSTATE[08006] [7] Connection refused Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?) I asked chatgpt for help, cleared cache and all of those solutions he gave me like reloading postgresql, changing firewall settings, created new laravel projects, migrating (it doesn't work most of the time) sometimes eventually I stopped getting the Internal Server Error and got the Symfony Exception but I Never got for it to work, on my PC on the offices it worked just fine (without Postgre tho) but here even without PostgreSQL it gives Symfony exception, I have tried countless solution and it doesn't seem to work.

Now I can use php artisan config:cache to fix the SQLSATE[08006] [7] error but it returns the file_put_contents(/home/user/Desktop/project/storage/framework/views/bae129cef9e600352d1c88ca55b5c61c.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory .
ErrorException
HTTP 500 Internal Server Error
and if I change any config file or do
composer dumpautoload to try and fix this other exception it returns the other one so I'm basically just switching between two exceptions and this problem doens't seem to have an end.

Now I created a new project and got everything rolling but without PostgreSQL, only normal MySQL, and would like to know how do I make a clean transfer to PostgreSQL

Change the db host to 127.0.0.1, that should fix this problem

That is the db host already, I think I had localhost before but changed and it doesn't fix anything
